# change month, year & date width individually in SelectDateWidget

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

In `SelectDateWidget` drop-down options, `month_names` need to be wider then days and years. How to make Months wider without affecting the width of other two drop-downs.

[image]

Comment: Did you by any chance added css that has set a fixed width on the `<select>`s?

Comment: yes my bad. I had width:20% in a div tag few levels above the actual selectdatewidget class, so even when i commented out width attr in selectdatewidget class, the width was proportional. 
But it would still be useful to be able to control the width of individual elements in selectdatewidget

Comment: Please provide the CSS and the HTML code.